# Webpage refreshes on submit buttton but no action happens

Tags: php

So, I am working on a web application and have a part where you should reset the password using the token.
I have managed to check is the token correct,and echo a new form for submitting a password on the same webpage.
However, once I click the submit button, no data is being updated.

I notice that $pass in the code isn't being set, and when I run the code without the isset($_POST['password']), the token table is updated, and the old password is replaced with the blank one.

```
 <?php 

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$token=$_POST['token'];


$query="SELECT email FROM token WHERE token=:token AND status=0"; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(":token" => $token));
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

 if ($count > 0)
 {
    if(!isset($_POST['password'])){  

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) $email=$row['email']; 

    }

    $pass=$_POST['password'];

    if(!isset($pass)){  
    echo '<form method="post">  
    Unesite novu lozinku:<input type="password" class="fadeIn second" name="password" id="password">  
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Promeni lozinku">  
    </form>  '
    ;}

    if (isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo $pass;

    $query1="UPDATE radnik SET lozinka =:pass WHERE email = '".$email."'";  
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare($query1);
    $stmt1->execute(array(":pass" => $pass)); 
    $r = $stmt1->rowCount;
    echo $r;
    if ($stmt1){
    $query2="UPDATE token SET status = 1 WHERE token=:token";  
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $stmt2->execute(array(":token" => $token));   
    echo "Lozinka je promenjena <a href='login.php'> Vrati se na pocetnu </a>"; 
    }
    if(!$stmt2)echo "Greska";  
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Where is your html form implementation?

Comment: you could make the `!isset` and `isset` both in one `if` by using the `else` or `elseif` statement

Comment: the problem should be in the fact that you have an `if` checking for the submit of one form, and inside you check for the second form's submit. but i think it never reaches that part of the code, therefor you could try to send the update password to a `handler.php` and then update the password

Comment: `<form method="post" action="updatePassword.php">`

Comment: Hi guys! I have tried to move it to separate file, but don't know how to transfer the token and email?

Comment: Put them into hidden form fields, or the session.